# Is there any udf function for add_months in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Can you help if there is any udf in scala which is equivalent to add_months in sql.

```
 add_months(startDate: date, numMonths: Int)
```

Comment: Can you let me know how i can use

Comment: by `udf`, do you mean spark udf ?

Comment: There is already a function in spark dataframe to do that. You don't need an UDF. Check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Which type is Date? 
If you are using spark and DataFrame there is a function already, you don't need to define your own udf:

```
def add_months(startDate: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,numMonths: Int): org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

Which can be used as follows:

```
df.withColumn(add_months($"field_with_date"), number)
```

If it's an standard `Date` class you can use `DateUtils` as follows:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils
DateUtils.addMonths(startDate, 1);
```